# How to make RSTP protocol for video streaming works on Windows 11?

Tags: video-streaming, streaming, rtsp, libvlc

The VLC player on Windows appears to have broken behaviour when streaming over different protocol. Here is an example:

```
CAMERA="PIXPRO ORBIT360 4K"

SIZE="3840x1920"

HTTP="#http{dst=localhost:8080/test.wmv}"
RTSP="#rtp{sdp=rtsp://:8090/test.wmv}"

CODEC="venc=x264{preset=veryfast,tune=zerolatency,intra-refresh,sync-lookahead=0,rc-lookahead=0,keyint=250},ab=128"

TRANSCODE="#transcode{$CODEC,scale=auto,acode=none,scode=none}"

SOUT="$TRANSCODE:$HTTP"

/c/Program\ Files/VideoLAN/VLC/vlc.exe -vvv \
  dshow:// :dshow-vdev="$CAMERA" :dshow-adev=none :dshow-size="$SIZE" \
  --sout "${SOUT}" \
  --no-audio --no-sout-all --sout-keep
```

This could successfully set up a streaming server at "localhost:8080/test.wmv", but once I switched to RTSP (according to https://docs.videolan.me/vlc-user/3.0/en/advanced/streaming/rtsp_session.html):

```
SOUT="$TRANSCODE:$RTSP"
```

No video was broadcasted, opening "rtsp://@:8090/test.wmv" could only yield a black screen.

How could this happen and what should be done to fix it?